# My Second Layout is not working(Tapestry 5)

Tags: layout, tapestry

I have two layouts and both are working in index page, but when I give to another the second one doesn't work. I don't know what the problem is, I'm new to tapestry.

my code is

```
    <html t:type="layout1" title="accountInfo VideoClub"
        xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_1_0.xsd"
             xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter">
               <head>

  <meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable"/>
  <meta content="black" name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style"/>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"/>
   <meta content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;   
     user-scalable=0;" name="viewport" />

    <title>Video Club</title>

    <link href="./layout/layout.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />  

     </head>

    <body>

     <div id="wrap"> 

<div id="scroll">

 <ul id="thelist"> 

    <div style="text-align:center;">
    <p><h1>Account info</h1>
    <t:actionlink t:id="getStatus"> <img src="../layout/images 
                      /sub.png"/>          
       </t:actionlink><br/><br/>
    <t:actionlink t:id="getStatuss"> <img src="../layout/images
             /cancel_sub.png"/> </t:actionlink><br/></p>

    </div>

    </ul>
</div>
    </div>
     </body>    

        </html>
```

Comment: Neither does anyone else without any code, error message or stacktrace.

Comment: "doesn't work" is a poor description of the problem. What result are you expecting? What is happening instead? Do you see any error message?

Answer (score 0):

Without the entire code (tml and java) we can't help you much.

Layout components in tapestry are plain components, which render their body with some content around it.

Please paste your code here.